# UnZip data in C#

Tags: c#, web-services, gzipstream

I'm new at C#, I writing a simple web service. It takes the zip file and decompress it in file system. In C# code is:

```
[WebMethod]
public String SetZip(string device_id, string file)
{
    if (device_id == null || device_id.Length == 0)
    {
        return "10;no auth data";
    }

    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();

    if (direcory == null)
    {
        return output.ToString();
    }

    string dirname = "c:\\temp\\" + direcory + "\\";

    if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(dirname))
    {
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(dirname);
    }

    string filename = dirname + "file1.txt";

    string text = UnZipStr(Convert.FromBase64String(file));

    File.WriteAllText(filename, text);

    output.AppendLine("0;done");

    return output.ToString();
}

public static string UnZipStr(byte[] input)
{
    using (MemoryStream memstream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (MemoryStream inputStream = new MemoryStream(input))
        {
            using (DeflateStream gzip =
              new DeflateStream(inputStream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
            {
                using (StreamReader reader =
                  new StreamReader(gzip, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8))
                {
                    return reader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And send zip data from java code:

```
    void callService(byte[] xmlData) {
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
    request.addProperty("device_id", AGENT);

    Deflater deflater = new Deflater();
    deflater.setInput(xmlData);
    deflater.finish();

     ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
     byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
     while (!deflater.finished()) {
         int byteCount = deflater.deflate(buf);
         baos.write(buf, 0, byteCount);
     }
     deflater.end();

     byte[] compressedBytes = baos.toByteArray();

    request.addPropertyIfValue("file", org.kobjects.base64.Base64.encode(compressedBytes));...}
```

At C# code I have Exception when read data from StreamReader

```
SoapFault - faultcode: 'soap:Server' faultstring:     'System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: ---> InvalidDataException: Block length does    not correspond to the complement.
System.IO.Compression.Inflater.DecodeUncompressedBlock(Boolean& end_of_block)
System.IO.Compression.Inflater.Decode()
System.IO.Compression.Inflater.Inflate(Byte[] bytes, Int32 offset, Int32 length)
System.IO.Compression.DeflateStream.Read(Byte[] array, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
System.IO.StreamReader.ReadBuffer()
System.IO.StreamReader.ReadToEnd()
Service.UnZipStr(Byte[] input) в c:\inetpub\wwwroot\WebSite\App_Code\Service.cs: at 94
Service.SetZip(String device_id, String file) в c:\inetpub\wwwroot\WebSite\App_Code    \Service.cs: at 73
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried to decompress with `GZipStream` instead of `DeflateStream`?

Comment: Yes and have other exception "Invalid magic number in the header of GZip. The transfer must go into a stream of GZip."

Comment: +1 'ing the question. Guy is a newbie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:** I've been digging around and there is a way to generate DEFLATE format data from Java that C# recognizes: you have to use the [`Deflater(int,boolean)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/zip/Deflater.html#Deflater%28int,%20boolean%29) constructor.  So change your Java code to:

```
Deflater deflater = new Deflater(Deflater.DEFAULT_COMPRESSION, true);
deflater.setInput(xmlData);
deflater.finish();
```

The reason is that by default the deflater emits a ZLIB header and checksum, which the C# `DeflateStream` doesn't expect.

---

It seems that Java and C# don't agree on the exact variety of "deflate" compression algorithm, but by my tests "gzip" should work:

This compresses `xmlData` in Java:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
OutputStream out = new GZIPOutputStream(baos);
out.write(xmlData);
out.close();
byte[] compressedBytes = baos.toByteArray();
```

This decompress `input` in C#:

```
using (MemoryStream inputStream = new MemoryStream(input))
{
  using (GZipStream gzip = new GZipStream(inputStream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
  {
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(gzip, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8))
    {
      return reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like @Joni Salonen has given an answer to the deflate problem, so I want to add a bit about architecture. To isolate the issue, you should separate the two concerns. First, you need to drop a zipped file. Then you need to deflate it. Then, focus on the problem area separately. You can always "pipeline" the two concerns later.

BTW, it is useful to have the raw zip file in many instances. It becomes a safety net when something does not work as planned, esp. if you only have one chance to capture the file.